# How to grep ip and port number as two diffrent variables

Tags: bash, grep

I've got txt file with ips in it and ports like this:

```
192.168.1.1:3389
192.168.1.2:5241    
192.168.1.3:3310    
192.168.1.4:445
```

How to grep to variables from it?
`$IP` and `$port`

where

`IP=192.168.1.1` ... and `PORT=4344`

without `:` char.

My target is to:

echo `"$IP"` `"$PORT"`
but need them (variables) both to be diffrent.

Comment: I don't see port `4344` in your sample input data. Are your input and output mismatched? What are your data sources? Exactly what commands have you tried, in order to solve this? Can you provide us with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can replicate whatever issue it is you're describing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Internal Field Separator to split the input for your `read` command:

```
$ while IFS=: read -r ip port; do printf 'IP=%s, port=%s\n' "$ip" "$port"; done < file.txt
IP=192.168.1.1, port=3389
IP=192.168.1.2, port=5241
IP=192.168.1.3, port=3310
IP=192.168.1.4, port=445
```

In this usage, `$IFS` is set only for the evocation of `read` and not globally.

Note that this is POSIX compliant, so it'll work in `/bin/sh` and other shells, not just `bash`.

If you wanted to get JUST IPs from your input file with external tools (`grep` or `cut`), you could use:

```
$ grep -o -E '^[^:]+' file.txt
```

or

```
$ cut -d: -f1 file.txt
```

Or similarly, just the ports:

```
$ grep -o -E '[^:]+$' file.txt
```

or

```
$ cut -d: -f2 file.txt
```

But if you want the pairs, separated, with shell commands processing each pair together, `grep` is insufficient for the job as it does not have any concept of "fields".

Comment: need only IP as variable and only port as another variable.  so they will be able to be echoed as pure ip address and pure port digits for further syntax script usage.

Comment: currently am getting this: 
IP= 123.143.52.134, port=5241   rest of text in textfile in the same row.

Comment: @AndrzejTI, include the details of your issue in your question. Obviously there's more going on here than you've communicated so far.

Answer (score 1):

While you can read the `IP` and `Port` into separate variables, you can also simply read the line as a whole and then use *parameter expansion with substring removal* to parse `IP` and `Port` into separate variables.

Bash provides a number of built-in parameter expansions, two relevant here are:

**Remove substring from 'Left'**

```
${var#substring}   trim 1st occurrence of substring from the left
${var##substring}  trim to last occurrence of substring from the left
```

**Remove substring from 'Right'**

```
${var%substring}   trim 1st occurrence of substring from the right
${var%%substring}  trim to last occurrence of substring from the right
```

(the `substring` can contain the wildcards (globs) `'*'` and `'?'` to match zero or more occurrences of and any single character, respectively)

Applied in your case you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -r "$1" ] || {  ## validate 1st argument is readable file
    printf "error: insufficient input.\nusage: %s filename\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do  ## read each line into line
    ip="${line%:*}"                       ## separate IP into ip
    port="${line#*:}"                     ## separate Port into port
    ## validate both ip and port oare non-empty and output
    [ -n "$ip" ] && [ -n "$port" ] && echo "IP: $ip  Port: $port"
done < "$1"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash ipport.sh ips.txt
IP: 192.168.1.1  Port: 3389
IP: 192.168.1.2  Port: 5241
IP: 192.168.1.3  Port: 3310
IP: 192.168.1.4  Port: 445
```

**Edit Per-Comment Updating Input Data**

If your data is:

```
109.104.213.202:4443 Dobrich Bulgaria 202.213.104.109.bergon.net
```

Then you simply need to add one-additional substring removal. Note how the first space occurs after the `IP:Port` combination you want? Just trim from the right upto the last occurrence of '' '` (space), e.g.

```
    line="${line%% *}"                    ## trim to last space from right
    ip="${line%:*}"                       ## separate IP into ip
    port="${line#*:}"                     ## separate Port into port
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Not working - i want to lynx --dump http://$IP:$PORT but when it substituting $PORT variable am getting port and some text that is after port number on source textfile. need to trim variable only to port digits.

Comment: 109.104.213.202:4443  Dobrich           Bulgaria            202.213.104.109.bergon.net

Comment: above is a exact row from my source file. need to extract it to two diffrent variables available to use in lynx ... http://$IP:$PORT and then in NC (netcat) as a diffrent syntax of ip [space] port - that is why there must be two variables.